# Running clean for all Gradle Tasks

Tags: gradle, build.gradle

I'm currently executing all my Gradle build tasks with the commands:

```
task runAll {
   dependsOn tasks.withType(JavaCPPTask)
}

build.dependsOn.add("runAll")
```

I can run clean on individual tasks by running:

```
gradle cleanTaskName
```

How can I adapt the generic `clean` target to run for all my tasks as I do for the `build` target?

TIA

Comment: Assuming your project has at least the 'base' plugin applied (`apply plugin: 'base'`), then running `clean` will simply delete the project build directory. If all of your project tasks place their outputs under the project build directory that should be sufficient.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  This specific project does not have a base output directory, each task has a specific file that it outputs to different directories.  I've added a depends on the clean target that specifies every task, but I was looking for a shortcut.

Comment: I see. You could generate the dependency list rather than explicitly list every project task. Try `clean.dependsOn project.tasks.collect { return "clean" + it.name.capitalize() }`.